# Format of Data is incorrect when fetching and receiving it from firebase in react native app

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux, fetch

I am trying to fetch my orders data which is stored in firebase in the correct format but when I am trying to see in console.log() then it shows incorrect format of data.

This is the data I am receiving from firebase.

```
Array [
  Order {
    "date": 1200,
    "id": "-Me6W4SzHB3RbV_3PdcO",
    "items": "u1",
    "totalAmount": Array [
      Object {
        "productId": "-Md76UnJ1I1lNhGgldH3",
        "productPrice": 1200,
        "productTitle": "Macbook Air M1 2020",
        "quantity": 1,
        "sum": 1200,
      },
    ],
  },
  Order {
    "date": 1200,
    "id": "-Me92VJEha-d-x5S3oya",
    "items": "u1",
    "totalAmount": Array [
      Object {
        "productId": "-Md76UnJ1I1lNhGgldH3",
        "productPrice": 1200,
        "productTitle": "Macbook Air M1 2020",
        "quantity": 1,
        "sum": 1200,
      },
    ],
  },
  Order {
    "date": 1200,
    "id": "-Me93LLXuho2T0D1Vpqx",
    "items": "u1",
    "totalAmount": Array [
      Object {
        "productId": "-Md76UnJ1I1lNhGgldH3",
        "productPrice": 1200,
        "productTitle": "Macbook Air M1 2020",
        "quantity": 1,
        "sum": 1200,
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

And, I got this when I have tried to console.log my orders I am receiving from action/orders where I am dispatching an action to fetch the data from firebase.

```
export const getOrders = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://shopping-app-62***-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/orders/u1.json"
      );

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Something went wrong!");
      }

      const resData = await response.json();
      const loadedOrders = [];

      for (const key in resData) {
        loadedOrders.push(
          new Order(
            key,
            "u1",
            resData[key].cartItems,
            resData[key].totalAmount,
            new Date(resData[key].date)
          )
        );
      }

      console.log(loadedOrders);

      dispatch({ type: GET_ORDER, orders: loadedOrders });
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  };
};
```

Order class:

```
import moment from "moment";

class Order {
  constructor(id, items, totalAmount, date) {
    this.id = id;
    this.items = items;
    this.totalAmount = totalAmount;
    this.date = date;
  }
  get readableDate() {
    return moment(this.date).format("MMMM Do YYYY, hh:mm");
  }
}

export default Order;
```

I have attached the image below to show how my data is stored in firebase.

[image]

Why I am getting an Array of Product detail in totalAmount and instead of date I am getting totalAmount?

Comment: Please provide your `Order` class in your question.

Comment: @samthecodingman sure, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are creating the `Order` objects:

```
new Order(
  key,
  "u1",
  resData[key].cartItems,
  resData[key].totalAmount,
  new Date(resData[key].date)
)
```

But it doesn't align with your constructor declaration:

```
constructor(id, items, totalAmount, date) {
  this.id = id;
  this.items = items;
  this.totalAmount = totalAmount;
  this.date = date;
}
```

The `"u1"` value is out of place.

```
constructor(id, unknown, items, totalAmount, date) {
  this.id = id;
  this.items = items;
  this.totalAmount = totalAmount;
  this.date = date;
  this.unknown = unknown;
}
```

---

You should either pass in an object of properties to the constructor and/or employ a tool like JSDoc or TypeScript to catch these problems in the future.

```
new Order({
  id: key,
  unknown: "u1",
  items: resData[key].cartItems,
  totalAmount: resData[key].totalAmount,
  date: new Date(resData[key].date)
})

constructor({ id, items, totalAmount, date, unknown }) {
  this.id = id;
  this.items = items;
  this.totalAmount = totalAmount;
  this.date = date;
  this.unknown = unknown;
}
```

Comment: Yes, due to 'u1' it was not working. Now I am getting data in the correct format. Thank you so much for your help.